# TypeORM filtrar colunas que foram transformadas

Tags: typescript, select, criptografia, typeorm, transform

Utilizei o [typeorm-encrypted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-encrypted), para encriptar colunas que contem dados sensíveis da aplicação, através do parâmetro *transformer* como mostrado a seguir:

```
    @PrimaryColumn()
    protocolo: number;

    @Column({
        nullable: false,
        transformer: CryptoTransformer,
    })
    nome: string;

    @Column({
        name: 'titular_nome',
        nullable: false,
        transformer: CryptoTransformer,
    })
    titularNome: string;
```

Conteúdo de *CryptoTransformer*:

```
import { EncryptionTransformer } from "typeorm-encrypted";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export default new EncryptionTransformer({
    key: `${process.env.DB_KEY}`,
    algorithm: 'aes-256-cbc',
    ivLength: 16,
    iv: `${process.env.DB_IV}`,
});
```

Gostaria de aplicar filtros nessas colunas, e estou tentando fazer isso utilizando o método *repository.createQueryBuilder()* do TypeORM, como mostrado a seguir:

```
const builder = repository.createQueryBuilder('em');
const nomeTeste = "maria";

builder.andWhere('LOWER(em.nome) LIKE LOWER(:nome) OR LOWER(em.titularNome) LIKE LOWER(:nome)', { nome: `%${nomeTeste}%` });
```

Porém, apesar de existir registros no banco que atendem aos filtros da query, nada é retornado, pois o valor do banco de dados está criptografado e não existe nenhuma substring "maria" nas colunas encriptadas.

Pensei em criptografar os filtros antes de realizar a query, mas não acho que essa seja a solução mais inteligente, além disso provavelmente filtros que utilizam o operador "LIKE" não funcionariam para comparar valores criptografados.

Poderiam me auxiliar a encontrar uma solução para aplicar filtros nessas colunas criptogradas?

Comment: Porque está usando criptografia?

Comment: @novic, são requisitos do cliente, imagino ser algo relacionado a LGPD. Caso algum imprevisto ocorra e o banco de dados vazar ou terceiros obterem acesso ao mesmo, a empresa tem "um ponto" a mais em sua defesa com essa criptografia dos dados, alegando que não foi negligente nesse quesito de proteção, realizando o que esteve ao alcançe  da mesma.

Comment: Você consegue fazer o inverso? tipo da criptografia para o que realmente significa?

Comment: Sim, isso é feito automaticamente pelo transformer, através do método "from". Ao realizar repository.find(), por exemplo, é obtido uma lista com os dados descriptografados. Isso me fez pensar em, talvez, sempre obter todos os registros do banco, através desse método, e realizar um .filter do JS no array aplicando os filtros do usuário. Será que a performance seria muito afetada nesse caso ?

Comment: Não faça isso ... isso é um erro grave e pode tornar sua aplicação muito lerda!